# Deserialize DirectoryObjects from the result of batch operation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

The batch operation contains requests to users' memberOf membership.

I am using Microsoft Graph SDK .NET and I'm not able to deserialize the response of batch operations (memberOf requests) to the proper type - that's the thing, I don't know what the proper type is and even the documentation is not helping here.

```
private async Task<IDictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<DirectoryObject>>> GetDirectoryObjectsAsync(
    IEnumerable<AbstractUser> users)
{
    var content = new BatchRequestContent();
    var requests = new List<TrackRequest>();
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        // _client ==> IGraphServiceClient
        var id = content.AddBatchRequestStep(_client.Users[user.Id.ToString("D")].MemberOf.Request());

        requests.Add(new TrackRequest(user.Id, id));
    }

    var result = new Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<DirectoryObject>>();
    var response = await _client.Batch.Request().PostAsync(content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    foreach (var request in requests)
    {
        var entities = await response.GetResponseByIdAsync<?? TYPE ??>(request.Id)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        // result.Add(request.User, entities);
    }

    return result;
}
```

What supposes to be the correct type to deserialize?

The response from the server is for example following.

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": "8404a86d-5232-4fd3-bdd2-fb1e26f05958",
            "status": 200,
            "headers": {
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                "OData-Version": "4.0",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8"
            },
            "body": {
                "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole",
                        "id": "ebd3402b-3df4-404a-8b54-deb669ba8bf5",
                        "deletedDateTime": null,
                        "description": null,
                        "displayName": null,
                        "roleTemplateId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole",
                        "id": "af0ecae5-6443-44ad-b23c-356ca0e22cd6",
                        "deletedDateTime": null,
                        "description": null,
                        "displayName": null,
                        "roleTemplateId": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You will have to create your own Type. The MS Graph REST APIs make no assumptions about the client.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense... Why would you use the SDK then? Also, there is defined type in "@odata.type".

Comment: I didn't know you were using an SDK, I thought those were custom classes you were using.

Answer (score 1):

The request to `_client.Users[user.Id.ToString("D")].MemberOf.Request()` returns the collection of DirectoryObjects inside the value property of the json response.

If you are using the graph SDK, this can be mapped to the `UserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesResponse` model.

You should therefore be able to sort this out by doing something similar to this

```cs
var collectionResponse = await batchResponse.GetResponseByIdAsync <UserMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesResponse> (requestItem).ConfigureAwait(false);
var directoryObjectPage = collectionResponse.Value;

foreach (var directoryObject in directoryObjectPage)
{
    if (directoryObject is Group)// you can do this if you are only interested in the group's instances in the response. The same can be done for other types as this API can return different derived types of DirectoryObject  
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I have a group instance");
    }
}
```